# MySQL create time and update time timestamp

Tags: sql, mysql, logging, time, timestamp

I am creating some tables where I want to store the time when a record was created and when it was last updated. I thought I could have two timestamp fields where one would have the value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and the other would have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. But I guess I can't do this because you can have only 1 timestamp field with a default value in a table?

How would you recommend I get and store the two times? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have two columns of type timestamp in one table.

The following works for MySQL 5.0

```
create table t 
(
  id integer, 
  created_at timestamp default current_timestamp, 
  updated_at timestamp
);
```

I think you are confusing this with SQL Server (where timestamp is not really a "time stamp" and there is indeed a limit on a single "timestamp" column)

Edit: But you will need a trigger to update the update_at column each time the row is changed.

Comment: That is correct, SQL Server's timestamp is really just a synonym for rowversion

Comment: This would execute, but the updated_at field doesn't get autoupdated on change. I thought adding the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on the updated_at column would take care of that. That is when it complains that this cannot be done.

Comment: Yes, as I said: you need to use a trigger to populate the updated_at column

Answer (score 32):

A good way to create fields like 'created' and 'updated' is

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` ( 
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
`updated` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() ON UPDATE now(),
`myfield` VARCHAR(255)
);
```

And its necessary to enter nulls into both columns during "insert":

```
INSERT INTO mytable (created,updated,myfield) VALUES (null,null,'blablabla');
```

And now, in all updates, the 'updated' field will have a new value with actual date.

```
UPDATE mytable SET myfield='blablablablu' WHERE myfield='blablabla';
```

Source : http://gusiev.com/2009/04/update-and-create-timestamps-with-mysql

Comment: This is the best solution I've found. The magic is that NULL is translated to NOW() on the insert. In a typical application, there will be more ways to update a row than to create it, so this feels like less maintenance than using up your "one now" on create and manually handling updates, using a separate trigger, or other approach.

Comment: Worked wonderfully!  Although in my situation I did not seem to need to pass in the null values and just the updated column changed.  Seems to work well.
`created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updated_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,` ...

Comment: this is best solution among all answers here!! Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 27):

As of MYSQL version 5.6.5 you can do this using DEFAULT and ON UPDATE.  No triggers are needed.

`ts_create` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

`ts_update` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Right now this is the best answer!

Comment: Note that `TIMESTAMP` has an upper limit of `2038-01-19 03:14:07`. In my experience 18 years pass rather quickly. The problem with `DATETIME` on the other hand is that with `UPDATE x='y', ts_update=NULL` the update column is *not* converted to the current timestamp but set to `NULL` whereas a `TIMESTAMP` column is still set to the current timestamp (At least that's what I found with MySQL 5.7). So decide for yourself which of the two is more acceptable for your use case.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the synonym `NOW()` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for brevity.  `ts_create TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(), ts_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW()`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no workaround for that restriction. You'll need to manually set (at least) one of the timestamps, the easiest way is just add `updated = NOW()` to the `UPDATE`-query.

Comment: +1 That does seem like a workable solution. I would have really loved it, if the server could do it automatically :)

Comment: Could be possible with triggers though, but I think that's not a great solution.

Comment: Usually it's done vice-versa: you manually specify `created=NOW()` and `updated` is set automatically. The reason is that you create a record 1 time but updates can be unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two columns: CREATE_TIME and UPDATE_TIME.

You might want to add CREATE_USER and UPDATE_USER.

Perhaps you'd want to have a 1:many relationship with name of column changed, old and new values.

It's all part of change data capture.  You could have CDC tables that are updated using triggers.

Comment: I do have 2 columns to store create time and update time - but I can't set the two default values I indicated above. I will look into what is CDC. Shouldn't there be a simple solution to this? I'd image this is a common scenario.

Comment: It is common, but I don't believe that MySQL has a built-in solution for it.  Oracle and SQL Server do.  Shouldn't be hard to do: a few tables and triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the current timestamp the way you suggested and fill in the created_at field with current date on insert.